# Use apache-curator for store kafka offset in spark-streaming on yarn. exception: User class threw exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, apache-curator

User class threw exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.curator.framework.api.CreateBuilder.creatingParentContainersIfNeeded()Lorg/apache/curator/framework/api/ProtectACLCreateModeStatPathAndBytesable;

**Run as local modle, no exception throw out.**

apache-spark: 2.2.0

apache-curator: 4.0.1, zookeeper-client: 3.4.5, zookeeper-server:3.4.5

exception code:

```scala
curator.create().creatingParentsIfNeeded().withMode(CreateMode.PERSISTENT).forPath(path, data)
```

maven pom:

```xml
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.curator</groupId>
                    <artifactId>curator-framework</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.curator</groupId>
                    <artifactId>curator-client</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.curator</groupId>
            <artifactId>curator-framework</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
                    <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
            <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.5</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

I try to exclute curator dependecy in spark-core, but still with the same exception.

Comment: Probably a better question for a Yarn/Spark group. This is a dependency/lib problem.

Comment: Change apache-curator version to 2.6.0, same as hadoop-common dependecy  is correct.